# Scrape data from website into Excel... but behind a login

Tags: html, excel, database, xpath, web-scraping

I'm currently playing a browsergame that's basically about breeding horses.

Now there are multiple factors that play into how good a horse is in tournaments and so on. Its about 30 or more numbers, e.g. things like "potential for barrel racing 25%, cutting 23%, ..."

I have an Excel sheet where I put in all these numbers that calculates the winning potential for every tournament, based on these numbers.

However, it takes quite a lot of time putting in all these numbers for every horse I want to look up, i currently have around 40.

Is there any way to get the data out of the html from the website into excel automatically? Sadly, the html is mostly `<div></div>` with nearly no classes or anything that would make it easy to address the specific numbers. I'll add a bit of the HTML asap to let you see what I mean:

```html
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="horse_skills" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="headline">Disziplin</div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="sub_headline">Fahren</div>
          <div class="horse_disciplines tab_padding">
            <h3>Dressurfahren</h3>
            <div class="disziplin" align="center">
              <div align="center" class="disziplin_balken">
                <div>
                  <div class="training_balken training" id="training_dressurfahren" style='width: 20%;'>
                    <span style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;" class="trainingtext_dressurfahren">20 %</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="potenzial_balken">
                <div style='width: 20%;'>
                  <span style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">20 %</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br><br>
```

In that example, I'd need the "20%" in the span tag under the `<div class="potenzial_balken">` the other one further up that says 20% doesn't help me. Oftentimes it's another number, it's just a coincidence it's the same in the example.

Plus, I have to login to my account to get to the page, and if I'm not logged in, I log in, and land on the starting page instead of the wanted page of the horse... and, if logged in, it takes about 2 hours and I'm getting logged out automatically.

Do you think it's still possible and if yes:

- How can I properly adress the data? I think It should work with XPath child nodes maybe...?
- How can I work around the login problem?

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Please, post what you have tried/coded and what errors are you getting. Read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Use querySelector

the login issue is a completely different issue

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("#horse_skills .potenzial_balken span").innerText)
```

```html
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="horse_skills" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="headline">Disziplin</div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="sub_headline">Fahren</div>
          <div class="horse_disciplines tab_padding">
            <h3>Dressurfahren</h3>
            <div class="disziplin" align="center">
              <div align="center" class="disziplin_balken">
                <div>
                  <div class="training_balken training" id="training_dressurfahren" style='width: 20%;'>
                    <span style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;" class="trainingtext_dressurfahren">20 %</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="potenzial_balken">
                <div style='width: 20%;'>
                  <span style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">20 %</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br><br>
```